# How do I export an SQL Server Compact table to an Excel in Windows CE with C#?

Tags: c#, excel, windows-mobile, compact-framework, sql-server-ce

I need to Export a table from SQL Server Compact 3.5 Table (*.sdf File) to an excel in Windows CE in a C# application.

Can any one please help me?

Is There Any easier way then querying all the data and then parsing it to an excel sheet?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should parse your table properties and than each row to create and fill in an Excel sheet.